# Sqlalchemy to query through a list of elements (including duplicates)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a query that I'm trying to work out and it just has 1 issue with it that I'm having a hard time resolving.

The sqlalchemy (python) query is as follows

```
def get_count(apple_ids: List[int]):
    q = (
        db.session()
        .query(
            func.sum(case([(Apple.is_green, 1)], else_=0)).label("green_count"),
            func.sum(case([(Apple.is_grouped, 5)], else_=1)).label("group_count"),
        )
        .filter(Apple.id.in_(apple_ids))
    )

    return q.one()
```

The issue arises if my apple_ids list has duplicates, i.e [10, 10].
In that case the sum is done only once for an Apple of id 10. But I need it to sum twice, since it is in the list twice.

The result from the query at this point (if Apple.is_green and Apple.is_grouped is True) is green_count = 1, group_count = 5. 
However I need it to be green_count = 2, group_count = 10.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to engineer this in pure SQL with a join (something like [this example](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/PGValues) if you're using postgres), but it's probably more trouble than it's worth. I would just query for `(Apple.id, Apple.is_green, Apple.is_grouped)`, stick it in a dictionary keyed on `Apple.id` and do the sum in python.

Answer (score 0):

If an object has duplicates in a table, trying to sum the data found in one of its columns can be achieved as follows:

```py
from sqlalchemy import func
from app.models import YourAppleTable


query = db.session.query(
    YourAppleTable.pick_a_column_eg_name, func.sum(
        YourAppleTable.column_whose_data_you_want_to_add)).group(
            YourAppleTable.pick_same_column_as_above).all()
```

In this example, `YourAppleTable` refers to your sqlalchemy model class. This model has a column called `pick_a_column_eg_name` whose data keeps repeating. We begin by identifying a duplicate object like this:

```py
query = db.session.query(YourAppleTable.pick_a_column_eg_name)
```

If you want to add data in another column, same model, based on the duplicate   object, then that is achieved as follows:

```py
query = db.session.query(
    YourAppleTable.pick_a_column_eg_name, func.sum(
        YourAppleTable.column_whose_data_you_want_to_add))
```

The `func.sum()` method from sqlalchemy helps with this. `func` is a special object instance which generates SQL functions based on name-based attributes. The returned object is an instance of `Function`, and is a column-oriented SQL element like any other. [Read more here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func). You will get the sum of the data found in the column `column_whose_data_you_want_to_add`.

To bundle the duplicate data, `group()` function is used. You want to use the same column you used earlier that has the duplicate data.

```py
query = db.session.query().group(YourAppleTable.pick_same_column_as_above)
```

`all()` is used to get ALL the results.

```py
query = db.session.query().group().all()
```

You should end up with something like this:

```py
item1    50
item2    15
```

Instead of:

```py
item1    20
item2    7
item1    10
item2    3
item1    20
item2    5
```